# Prove the inequality $|z^2 - \pi| < \varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

> Given $\varepsilon < 1$, prove that if $|z - \sqrt \pi| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$, then $$|z^2 - \pi| < \varepsilon$$

**My attemps**

In order to prove this inequality, I have been trying different things but I keep getting stuck.

First of all, I saw that $|z^2 - \pi| = |z - \sqrt \pi| \cdot |z + \sqrt \pi|$, so there´s a start.

By the triangular inequality, $|z \pm \sqrt \pi| \leq |z| + |\sqrt \pi|$. Therefore
$$|z^2 - \pi| = |z - \sqrt \pi| \cdot |z + \sqrt \pi| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4} \cdot |z + \sqrt \pi| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{4} (|z| + \sqrt \pi)$$
Since $\sqrt \pi < 2$, then
$$\frac{\varepsilon}{4} (|z| + \sqrt \pi) = \frac{\varepsilon}{4} |z| + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} \pi <  \frac{\varepsilon}{4} |z| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
If I could prove that $|z| \leq 2$, then I'll be done but I couldn't figure out how.

Other approach I took was trying mean inequalities:
$$|z^2 - \pi| = |z - \sqrt \pi| \cdot |z + \sqrt \pi| \leq (\frac{|z - \sqrt \pi| +|z + \sqrt \pi|}{2})^2$$
$$= \frac{|z - \sqrt \pi|^2 + 2|z - \sqrt \pi||z + \sqrt \pi|  +|z + \sqrt \pi|^2}{2}$$
$$= \frac{z^2 + 2 \sqrt \pi z + \pi + 2z^2 - 2\pi + z^2 - 2 \sqrt \pi z + \pi }{4} = z^2$$
I could not reach anywhere neither.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: You should add the tag for complex number to make clear that you are looking for this kind of solution.

Comment: The last fraction is wrong because we are dealing with complex numbers, the result is not $z^2.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to estimate $|z+\sqrt{\pi}|$ differently:

$$\begin{array}{rcll}|z+\sqrt{\pi}|&=&|z-(-\sqrt{\pi})|\\&\le&|z-\sqrt{\pi}|+|\sqrt{\pi}-(-\sqrt{\pi})|&\text{triangle inequality}\\&<&\frac{\varepsilon}{4}+2\sqrt{\pi}\\&<&\frac{1}{4}+2\sqrt{\pi}&\text{ as }\varepsilon<1\\&\approx &3.795\\&<&4\end{array}$$

so then $|z^2-\pi|=|z-\sqrt{\pi}|\cdot|z+\sqrt{\pi}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}\cdot 4=\varepsilon$.

Comment: Ah, we were editing simultaneously

Answer (score 3):

$|z^2 - \pi| =|z-\sqrt{\pi}|\times|z-\sqrt{\pi} +2\sqrt{\pi}|< \frac{\varepsilon}{4}\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{4}+2\sqrt{\pi}\right)<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}\times4=\varepsilon$

Answer (score 3):

Let $w=z-\sqrt \pi$ then $z+\sqrt \pi=w+2\sqrt \pi$ and

$$|z^2 - \pi| =|z - \sqrt \pi||z + \sqrt \pi|=|w||w+2\sqrt \pi|< \frac{\varepsilon}{4}(|w|+2\sqrt \pi)=\frac{\varepsilon^2}{16}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\sqrt \pi<\varepsilon$$